# Angular - Parse string as {{ dataObject + VARIABLE }} where VARIABLE = 'object?.key.something | pipe'

Tags: angular

I'm creating a custom table component, that gets data for each row / column.

Each column, gets data from a main object, but I want to parse a string as 'variable'

so imagine this:

```
var columns = [{
  columnVariableString: 'key?.something | pipeSomething'
}]

<td *ngFor="let column from columns">
  {{ dataObject + column.columnVariableString }}
</td>
```

where the template variable becomes `{{ dataObject.key?.something | pipeSomething }}`

So in a way its 'variable building' or concatenating strings together to make a single variable.

So instead of writing a template variable fully:

```
<td>
  {{ dataObject.someKey?.more }}
</td>
```

I want to 'build' a template variable like the template compiler does

```
var variablePiece = 'someKey?.more';
    <td>
      {{ dataObject + variablePiece }}
    </td>
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to achieve. Can you try with an [mcve]? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Agreed with @bracco23. Please share the stackblitz with expected output

Comment: You just can't do that. Code is not just a string that you can evaluate. It needs to be compiled.

Comment: @JBNizet I was afraid of that indeed. I Guess the only way is to create a template and pass it the variable with 'let-*' to inject it in the column. thanks